# No me funciona el conteo del for en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Quisiera hacer un bucle repetitivo para llenar un array y que es este sea comparado si es un numero o no pero el ciclo for no me contea los ciclos y se corta al primer dato numerico

Aca abajo dejo el codigo es javascript

```
let piloto1 = [];
let piloto2 = [];

for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if (i < 1)
    {
    piloto1[0] = prompt("ingrese el nombre del piloto 1");
    }
  else if (i < 9 )
    {
      var tiempo;
      var tiempoP;
      if (isNaN(tiempo))
      {
        do {
          tiempo = Number(prompt("ingrese el tiempo de la carrera " + i));
        } while (isNaN(tiempo));
      }
      if (isNaN(tiempoP))
      {
        do {
          tiempoP = Number(prompt("ingrese el tiempo penalizado de la carrera " + i));
        } while (isNaN(tiempoP));
        piloto1[i] = tiempo + tiempoP;
      }
    }
}

console.log(piloto1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que las declaraciones de las variables tiempo se encuentren fuera del for y justo antes de finalizar el for, les asignes valores de null. Ya que en cada ciclo se repiten los valores de la pasada anterior y como estos son valores numéricos, el if los ignora.

```
var tiempo;
var tiempoP;

for() {
...
tiempo = null;
tiempoP =null;
}
```

Comment: intente lo que me dijiste y ahoro no salta el prompt para colocar el primer dato de la carrera

Comment: ya resolvi el problema no tenia que declarar el tiempo en null ya que sino no me hacia la validacion del if y por ende la solucion fue declarar la variable tiempo y tiempoP como un caracter de valor "a"

Answer (score 0):

isNaN siempre es falso, por que siempre lo declaras antes de darle un valor es decir la crearlo es tipo numerico pero no tiene dato por lo tanto su primer valor es empty eso se repite 9 veces, lo ideal es que ese if este dentro del DoWhile

Comment: me funciona la comparación numero letra lo que no me funciona es el ciclo for que no pasa del valor 1

Comment: var tiempo = NaN asi utiliza el codigo.